# Covert src files in R pagate from C++ to R

Tags: r, rcpp, rcppeigen

**Updated information**

I finally got to make `souceCpp` works, but still couldn't get the source code in R.

I tried the following:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp('src/vinecopulib-interface.cpp')
> try <- Rcpp::sourceCpp('src/vinecopulib-interface.cpp')
> try
$functions
 [1] "pseudo_obs_cpp"                 "bicop_check_cpp"                "bicop_select_cpp"              
 [4] "bicop_pdf_cpp"                  "bicop_cdf_cpp"                  "bicop_hfunc1_cpp"              
 [7] "bicop_hfunc2_cpp"               "bicop_hinv1_cpp"                "bicop_hinv2_cpp"               
[10] "bicop_sim_cpp"                  "bicop_loglik_cpp"               "bicop_par_to_tau_cpp"          
[13] "bicop_tau_to_par_cpp"           "rvine_structure_cpp"            "rvine_structure_check_cpp"     
[16] "rvine_structure_sim_cpp"        "rvine_matrix_check_cpp"         "vinecop_check_cpp"             
[19] "vinecop_inverse_rosenblatt_cpp" "vinecop_rosenblatt_cpp"         "vinecop_sim_cpp"               
[22] "vinecop_pdf_cpp"                "vinecop_cdf_cpp"                "vinecop_loglik_cpp"            
[25] "vinecop_mbicv_cpp"              "vinecop_select_cpp"             "fit_margins_cpp"
```

Then, I tried to get, `try$functions[26]` but did not return me the function in R code.

[image: as shown in the attached figure]I have installed the `R` package. I tried to convert some files from `src` into `R` language. I do the following steps:

- Open the package in the `R` console
- Open one file of the `src` folder as a `C++` file.
- Then, use `soucreCpp(filename.cpp)`

but got the following:

```
 > Rcpp::sourceCpp('src/vinecopulib-interface.cpp')
In file included from vinecopulib-interface.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/fadhahalanazi/Downloads/rvinecopulib-master/src/../inst/include/vinecopulib-wrappers.hpp:15:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:540:[![as shown here][1]][1]
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the compilation note shown is a **warning message**; not an error.

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30:
 warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
```

To get around the diagnostic message, just add to the top of each header file:

```cpp
#define EIGEN_PERMANENTLY_DISABLE_STUPID_WARNINGS

// Then, include the header file
#include <RcppEigen.h>
```

For details on the define, see: [`/inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h)

As you are using `sourceCpp()` instead of compiling a package, make sure to also include:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
```

Second, I have a feeling that the opening prompt is missing the compilation failure message. As hinted previously, the compilation is being done in the context of a single script with `sourceCpp()`; however, working with an existing *R* package such as `rvinecopulib`, the compilation must be done by compiling the entire package. That is, the package needs to be created using `R CMD build <pkg>` and, subsequently, installed with `R CMD install <pkg>_x.y.z.tar.gz`

Alternatively, you can use the [`Build` panel of an RStudio project](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-the-RStudio-IDE) or [`devtools`](https://devtools.r-lib.org/index.html)' functions: [`devtools::build()`](https://devtools.r-lib.org/reference/build.html) and [`devtools::install()`](https://devtools.r-lib.org/reference/install.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Really appreciated. But I have got an error: > `devtools::build("rvinecopulib") Error: `pkg` must exist` `

Comment: I edit my question.  Thanks a lot.